Stokes Theorem on standard simplices
I was studying the de Rham homomorphism, and more specifically Stokes theorem for chains, and I'm wondering whether one could avoid talking about manifolds with corners and just give a definition of integration along chains in the following way: if $\omega$ is a $k$-form on a manifold $M$ and $\sigma \colon \Delta^k \rightarrow M$ is smooth, we set
\begin{equation}
\int_{\sigma} \omega := \int_{int(\Delta^k)} (\sigma_{|int(\Delta^k)})^*\omega.
\end{equation}
This is basically the same as the usual definition, since when we integrate over $\Delta^k$ we actually forget about the boundary, since it has measure $0$. One can show quite easily that this is always finite. Next I'd like to define the integral over the boundary in the following way
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial \Delta^k} \omega := \sum_{i = 1}^{k} (-1)^i\int_{int(\Delta^{k-1})}((\sigma \circ F_{i,k})_{|int(\Delta^{k-1})})^*\omega
\end{equation}
where the $F_{i,k}$ are the boundary maps identifying the faces of $\Delta^k$ with the standard $(k-1)$-simplex. Again, this is just the usual integration along the boundary.
Finally, I'd like to prove Stokes theorem. At this point, it's pretty much all done except proving it for forms on $\Delta^k$. That is, I'd like to show the following holds:
if $\omega$ is a $(k-1)$-form on $\mathbb{R}^k$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Delta^k} d\omega = \int_{\partial \Delta^k} \omega.
\end{equation}
Now this is where my question starts: I feel like this can be proven by induction (the case $k = 1$ being the fundamental theorem of calculus) by slicing $\Delta^k$ with affine hyperplanes $H_t = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^k \ | \ x^k = t \}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and then using Fubini's theorem. The $A^{k-1}_t := \Delta^k \cap H_t$ are just affine $(k-1)$-simplices.
To sum it up, does someone know if there is an easy proof of this version of Stokes theorem?

Look at Spivak’s Calculus on Manifolds for a treatment of integration on chains.

Unfortunately Spivak works with cubes, while I need simplices.

You can easily make the necessary mental changes. Or if I remember correctly, one of the supplements in chapter 8 of Abraham Marsden Ratiu’s Tensor Analysis on Manifolds treats Stokes’ theorem on chains using simplicies.

Have you worked out the computations in dimensions 2 and 3? That should show you how to write out the induction.
